# Pre-populating a Persistent Volume on OpenShift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I have created a cluster on OpenShift Online for experimental use. My Deployment which I am trying to create needs to have a pre-populated data volume before use. All of the deployments should use the same volume and that means that the Persistent Volume Claim needs to be configured as ReadOnlyMany.

I have created a Persistent Volume Claim as well, but I am not sure is it possible to pre-populate a ReadOnlyMany volume on OpenShift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have created a Persistent Volume Claim as well, but I am not sure is it possible to pre-populate a ReadOnlyMany volume on OpenShift?

Not really that's what `ReadOnlyMany` is, it's Read Only. You can use something else to pre-populate your volume prior (like a VM/Host/Container, or even another Kubernetes cluster if you remove the volume after pre-populating and `Retain` it). It probably won't work with the same Kubernetes cluster though unless the volume allows you to change from something else (`ReadWriteOnce`, `ReadWriteMany`) to `ReadOnlyMany`.

You didn't specify what type of [Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) you are using but you could potentially use `ReadWriteMany` and manage access to write using plain [*nix filesystem permissions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm). Then you can run your pods as a specific user using a [`SecurityContext`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/).

✌️